# How can I pause in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to write this bash loop for zsh

```
while true; do echo "print something"; read -p "pause"; done
```

This loop echos, then waits for the user to press enter.  If I enter it as is, the read statement doesn't pause, causing zsh to infinitely echo "print something" without waiting for the user to press enter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like `-p` does something different in `zsh`.  You will probably need something like `read some_variable\?pause`.

Comment: Using `_` doesn't work: zsh throws an error `zsh: read-only variable: _
`.  Anything else works though.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 36):

In `zsh`:

```
read -s -k '?Press any key to continue.'
```

From `man zshbuiltins`:

- `-s` Don't echo back characters if reading from the terminal.
- `-k` Read only one character.
- `name?prompt` Name is omitted, thus user input is stored in the `REPLY` variable (and we ignore it). The first argument contains a `?`, thus the remainder of this word is used as a prompt on standard error when the shell is interactive.

To include a newline after the prompt:

```
read -s -k $'?Press any key to continue.\n'
```

`$''` is explained under `QUOTING` in `man zshmisc`.

Finally, a `pause` function that takes an arbitrary prompt message in a script that does what the OP asks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

pause() read -s -k "?$*"$'\n'

while true; do
    echo "print something"
    pause "pause"
done
```

Answer (score 13):

Since this is about the only search result I could find, and I found it helpful but still a bit confusing, here is another way of putting it: If all you want to do is echo a line of text and wait for the user to press enter ...
`read \?"I am waiting for you to press [Enter] before I continue."`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/zsh

pause()
{
    echo "$*"; read -k1 -s
}
```

now we can call the function with any prompt text:

```
pause "paused! press any key to continue"
pause "you can write anything here :)"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a way that works in both `bash` and `zsh`, and ensures I/O to/from the terminal:

```
# Prompt for a keypress to continue. Customise prompt with $*
function pause {
  >/dev/tty printf '%s' "${*:-Press any key to continue... }"
  [[ $ZSH_VERSION ]] && read -krs  # Use -u0 to read from STDIN
  [[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && </dev/tty read -rsn1
  printf '\n'
}
export_function pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in zsh **and** bash:

```
printf >&2 '%s ' 'Press any key to continue ...'
read ans
```